# Log4j 2 rolling file with wrong timestamp

Tags: java, log4j2

I have following Roling file:

```
<RollingFile name="mylog"
                 filePattern="${sys:server.output.dir}/logs/mylog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"
                 ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %-5p %c %m%n\n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="100000000" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy />
    </RollingFile>
```

But I am getting wrong timestamp.

If the log is created on **24th of June** it is called **mylog_2019-06-23.1.log** and it contains files from **24th**.

Last files generated to better illustrate:

```
mylog_2019-06-20.1.log  - generated on 21st at 23:50 - contains logs from 21st

mylog_2019-06-21.1.log  - 22nd at 23:50 - contains logs from whole 22nd

mylog_2019-06-22.1.log  - 23rd at 00:00 - contains logs from 23rd to 7 AM

mylog_2019-06-23.1.log  - 23rd at 23:50 - contains logs from 23rd 7 AM to end of day

mylog_2019-06-23.2.log  - 24th at 00:00 - contains logs from today (24th) until now
```

What am I doing wrong?
(same happens with any interval, e.g. minutes - the stamp is always one unit off)

Comment: Have you checked the system timezone where the application is running? That might be the issue.

Comment: Time zone is the same on my local machine, where I test it and on the server (being +1).

Comment: If the logs are of server then, application will pick the time of the server only, or you could force it to take the time of a certain timezone.

Comment: But it is happening on my local machine too (testing locally). Moreover when it was in log4j 1 it worked, only when I updated log4j to v2 and of course I had to rewrite the config, but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @stove what is log4j 2 version?

Comment: @Oleksandr 2.11.1

Comment: I looked through PatternProcessor.getNextTime. It uses default Calendar.getInstance().
If Locale\TimeZone is supposed to be changed in an application after Logger initialization then I guess we have that strange behavior. I couldn't reproduce it locally but if I pass filePattern="/logs/mylog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}{GMT+12}.%i.log" I have the same issue as you. So I would suggest to experiment with {GMT+X} in the pattern. Also would be nice to make sure that App locale is initialized before any Logger.

Comment: @Oleksandr sorry for not answering sooner, I was solving multiple issues, this not being priority. Anyway, Playing with GMT+X didn't help, the timezone is set correctly and it didn't help. There seems to be bug in DirectWrite Rollover Strategy, If I use default rollover strategy (and set filename attribute) the stamps are suddenly coming out correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I had to add fileName attribute to RollingFile element and change strategy to  and it works now. Nomax is there just not to limit number of files to keep.

The side effect is that now the logs are first logged into mylog.log and when the file gets rollovered it gets renamed to mylog_{stamp}.log.

```
<RollingFile name="myLog"
                     fileName="${sys:server.output.dir}/logs/mylog.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:server.output.dir}/logs/mylog_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"
                     ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %-5p %c %m%n\n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: I would have suggested that you ry upgrading to a later release. Several problems similar to this were fixed in 2.11.2

Comment: @rgoers I am actualy using 2.12.0. But thanks for the tip.